# Erro em Requisição SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soapclient

Venho tentando me conectar em um WSDL, porém, sem êxito.

O fornecedor do web service me passou um arquivo `xxx.wsdl` e me passou as credenciais para a conexão. Venho tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
$client = new SoapClient('xxx.wsdl', $credentials); // Array com user e pass
```

Valido as funções disponíveis:

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Me retorna:

```
TipoDeRetorno minhaFuncao(TipoDeDado dado);
```

Quando tento executar a função/método dá erro:

```
$client->minhaFuncao(null); // Dá erro
$client->__call('minhaFuncao', [null]); // Dá erro
$client->__soapCall('minhaFuncao', [null]); // Dá erro
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
SoapFault in MinhaClasse.php line 80:
Server
```

Apenas a mensagem `Server` como erro. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Segundo o manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapfault.php e também a documentação https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_fault.htm

Esse elemento é um envelope, tente dar um print_r ou um `__toString()`

Comment: Obrigado por comentar @KhaosDoctor, nesse caso, a mensagem `Server` vem em forma de Exception, não como uma mensagem do wsdl.

Comment: `minhaFuncao()` exige `TipoDeDado` e você está passando `null`. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Coloquei `null` no exemplo, mas mesmo que passe um array com os campos necessários, dá erro!

Comment: Entre em contato com o fornecedor da WSDL para ver se o serviço está realmente funcionando corretamente pois pode ser algum erro por parte do SERVER.

Comment: Para chamar corretamente você tem que passar uma instância de objeto `TipoDeDado`, não um array.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que seu código ali está exatamente como executado, você está passando o tipo de dado errado pra função, pois `minhaFuncao()` exige um parâmetro do tipo `TipoDeDado` e vai falhar se passar `null` ou `array` ou qualquer outro tipo.

tente algo como:

```
// Instancie primeiro um objeto do tipo TipoDeDado
$dados = new TipoDeDado($args);
$client->minhaFuncao($dados);
```

Comment: Mesmo nesse caso, ele segue dando o mesmo erro. Fiz exatamente dessa forma.

Comment: Fiz tbm assim: `$client->minhaFuncao(new TipoDeDado())` e o erro segue o mesmo. Vou posicionar o fornecedor pra ver se ele complementa algo sobre esse erro e complemento aqui.

Comment: Você tem que conferir como se instancia o Objeto. Se não é algo do seu código deve haver alguma documentação a respeito. Talvez tenha que passar os dados do array no momento de instanciar? Aí só pesquisando mesmo. O fato é que nenhum outro tipo vai funcionar se o método só aceita este.

Comment: Sim, estou aguardando a resposta do fornecedor pra ver se estou falhando em algo ou se o wsdl deles que está com problemas.